# creating an illusion of a multi page form using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to php and java script (one week) and im trying to create a multi-page form with a simple and compact script. The 2nd page will do all the validation and security checks and look like a conformation page that will show all errors. but i cant get the buttons to move through the field sets.
  What am I doing wrong?
here is a sample site:
http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/631/

```js
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('fieldset').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('fieldset:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('fieldset').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('fast', function () {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
        $next.css('z-index', 1);
    });

}
```

```css
/*form styles*/
#AUTO {
display:table;/*makes div fill content*/
width: 345px;
height:auto;
position: relative;
border:1px solid red; /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
}
#AUTO fieldset {
width: 345px;
border:1px solid red; /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/

}
#miles{
display:none;/*spamer fills this out and it gets rejected my mail script*/
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#AUTO fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
display: none;/*remove to see all feildsets*/

}
.action-button {
}



}
```

```html
<h1>goals</h1>
    <p>1. To be able to switch "fieldset" by clicking next and previous button's without seeing the transition.&#x2717;(nope)</p> 
    <p>2.for the div to fill the content without specifying height as some buttons will expand to reveal more options.&#x2713;(i think)</p>
    <p>3.for the next and previous buttons NOT to disapear after clicking it for the first time.&#x2717;(unknown)</p>

<form id="AUTO"   method="post" action="page2.php">
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
page 1  illusion<br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="button"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
page 2  illusion<br>page 2  illusion<br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" id="button" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" id="button" />
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
page 3  illusion<br>page 3  illusion<br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="ALMOST DONE" id="button" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" id="button" />
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
page 4 illusion<br>page 4 illusion<br>page 4 illusion<br>page 4 illusion<br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="FINAL STEP" id="button" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" id="button" />
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
page 5 illusion<br>page 5 illusion<br>page 5 illusion<br>page 5 illusion<br>page 5 illusion<br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="DONE" id="button" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" id="button" />
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
page 6  illusion<br>page 6  illusion<br>page 6  illusion<br>page 6  illusion<br>page 6  illusion<br>page 6  illusion<br>
<input name="fakeinput" type="text" id="miles" placeholder="only bots will fill input out"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" id="button" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" id="button" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: First, you can not use the same `id` attribute for multiple html elements. You can use `class` instead of `id` if you want to use the same class for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the click events, you need to use class selector like `.next` instead of id selector `#next`. I updated your code to following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').on('click', getNext);
    $('.previous').on('click', getPrev);
});
```

You were also using wrong selector for 'previous' and i updated it from `#prev` to `.previous`.

and your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/633/

Comment: the fiddle works but whenever i copy and paste it in my editor it don't work there

Comment: Can you update your fiddle with your updated editor code and pass me the link so I can take a look at your updated editor code.

Comment: i got it can how would i go about making it so that switches from one div to the next without seeing the transition?

Comment: You can update your `transition()` function to do `$curr.hide();` and `$next.show();` instead of using `fadeIn()`. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rCd26/640/